# Send PDF file to network printer using ipp in Java

Tags: java, pdf, network-printers

I'm using the below code to send pdf file into network printer. 
The command is send but file not print actual data. 
Please help me.

```
String urlF="ipp://192.168.0.115:9100/printer/TOSHIBA e-STUDIO2802ASeries PCL6";
                String urlS=urlF.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                URI printerURI = new URI(urlS);
                IppPrintService svc = new IppPrintService(printerURI);
                stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:/pdfurl-guide.pdf"));
                DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
                Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(stream, flavor, null);
                DocPrintJob job = svc.createPrintJob();
                job.print(myDoc, null);
```

Comment: What IPP Implementation does your code depend on?

Comment: I think you've made up the IPP URL - it looks very wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for your response. Finally I solved this by using CUPS Server.

Answer (score 0):

Your [printer model](https://www.toshibatec.com/products_overseas/MFP/eS2802AF_series/) doesn't seem to support what you are trying to do.

1. PDL: PDF not supported
2. protocol: no IPP support (default port ist 631)

In case the used ipp implementation has good error handling you should see some kind of error message or exception, when you run the code.

**UPDATE**

Using this [ipp-client](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin) you can submit a PDF file to a printer (or CUPS) that supports this document format:

```
new IppPrinter(URI.create("ipp://myprinter")).printJob(
    File("mydocument.pdf"), documentFormat("application/pdf")
);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your response. Finally I solved this by using CUPS Server.